# Filter a list based on another list while keeping the original type

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

Given a list `A` of bool elements and another list `B` with the same length, the goal is to do something essentially

```
B = [B[i] for i in xrange(len(A)) if A[i]]
```

However, sometimes `B` is not a basic python list; for example, it might be created with `manager.list()`, where `manager` is an instance of `Manager()` from the `multiprocessing` module.  The above list comprehension will turn it into a plain list, which will lose the desired function (to share data between subprocesses).

What I come up with is something like

```
def my_filter(A, B):
    c = 0
    for i in xrange(len(A)):
        if not A[i]:
            B.pop(i-c)
            c = c + 1
```

So that `my_filter(A, B)` will turn `B` into its sub-list where the elements of `A` are `True`.

However, this is a bit "ugly".  Is there a more "pythonic" way to do this?

Comment: https://medium.com/on-coding/shorter-code-is-inconsiderate-41cce917b51b

Comment: it can be ... but it can also be elegant

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
B = B.__class__([itemB for itemA,itemB in zip(A,B) if itemA])
```

or probably better

```
B[:] = [itemB for itemA,itemB in zip(A,B) if itemA]
```

Comment: That will not work if the __init__ requires two or more arguments.  And I guess the fist A should be B, right?

Comment: see my seconds suggestion that should work with both `manager.list` and `list` ...